# django model choices make no effect on saved data

Tags: django, django-models

Following the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#choices) I try to make a choices field in my 
**models.py**:

```python
class MyModel(Model):

    ACTION_CHOICES = (
        ('d', 'delete'),
        ('c', 'create'),
        ('u', 'update'),
    )

    action = CharField(max_length=1, choices=ACTION_CHOICES)
```

But when I run it with

```
 action = MyModel(action='create')
 action.save()
```

and check the database **the action is not `c`, but `create`**. Furthermore even restriction to max_length doesn't affect on it. Ok, I moved on and tried to make it in this way:

**models.py**

```
class MyModel(Model):

    ACTION_CHOICES = (
        (1, 'delete'),
        (2, 'create'),
        (3, 'update'),
    )

    action = IntegerField(max_length=1, choices=ACTION_CHOICES)
```

**code.py**:

```
action = MyModel(action='create')
action.save()
```

But I got an error that str field can't be saved like int (database has the int field, but MyModel.action is str) What Do I miss here? Aren't choices supposed to convert value on save?

Best regards,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are several questions in your post:

1) The `choices` can only restrict what can be entered through a Django form. When you manually instantiate your object you can insert any value. So

```
action = MyModel(action='create')
```

actually inserts the string `create` into the action column.

2) Normally `max_length` should stop you from inserting a string longer than 1 character into that column, but I guess you are using SQLite which has [no restriction on VARCHAR lengths](http://www.sqlite.org/faq.html#q9).

3) Django has no easy conversion from the display values to choice keys. You can have a look at [django-model-utils](https://django-model-utils.readthedocs.org/en/latest/utilities.html#choices) for a wrapper on choices.

Comment: I already used it in this way and I'm like a 110% sure that it should do the trick. Here's the [code](https://github.com/Deathangel908/djangochat/blob/master/story/registration_utils.py#L57-58) where variable `sex` is set to 'Female'.  And the variable `profile` is instance of `UserProfile`. [Here](https://github.com/Deathangel908/djangochat/blob/master/story/models.py#L11-15)'s its model. The database value is boolean. I've just checked it.  [here](https://github.com/Deathangel908/akoidan_bio/blob/master/akoidan_bio/models.py#L87-L96) it doesn't work. I'm just so blind can't find difference.

Comment: I don't know about that code but it is possible that you are inserting everybody as 'Male' since any non-null string is equivalent to boolean True.

Answer (score 5):

When you define choices

```
ACTION_CHOICES = (
    (1, 'delete'),
    (2, 'create'),
    (3, 'update'),
)
```

the values stored in the db are 1, 2, 3, while 'delete', 'create' etc.. are just labels, just to explain, the prev choices results in such select input element:

```
<select>
    <option value="1">delete</option>
    <option value="2">create</option>
    <option value="3">update</option>
</select>
```

Choices are not supposed to convert value on save, are supposed to map db values with labels, and used when rendering the form widget and when retrieving the field representation (get_field_display). But if you set directly the value of a column it doesn't play a role.

If you want to use "talking keys" you can define them as class properties, like

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    DELETE_ACTION = 1
    CREATE_ACTION = 2
    UPDATE_ACTION = 3

    ACTION_CHOICES = (
        (DELETE_ACTION, 'delete'),
        (CREATE_ACTION, 'create'),
        (UPDATE_ACTION, 'update'),
    )
```

Then you can do

```
action = MyModel(action=MyModel.CREATE_ACTION)
```

and it would be fine

Comment: Right you are, that's what I'm trying to reach, and I want the values `1` `2` `3` to be stored in the database. I set lable to `delete` and I want it in the db like `1`. But instead I see `delete`.

Comment: but you are setting directly the field: action = MyModel(action='create'), if you set a column this way you have to respect the column type, the choices tuple is used when rendering the form widget or retrieving the 'textual' value, not when you set directly a field value

Comment: So how do I set the lable? I don't wanna know that it should be stored in the database.  That what's the tuple conversion for. I set the lable to 'delete', the tuple converts it to `1` on the django database layer. Isn't it what are choices for?

Comment: yes, when you insert values through a form and a select widget, not when you set directly the column value, since after all the column type is an integer

Comment: Could you please take a look at my [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28880860/django-model-choices-make-no-effect-on-saved-data/28881497#comment46024893_28881497), just refresh the page after click.

Comment: if you manually set a column value, just do not rely on choices tuples. Just set the expected value type as you would do with a direct db query. In my example I had given such db values (1, 2, 3) a "name" which is more readable, but still pointing to the integer value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72352/discussion-between-deathangel908-and-abidibo).